# Saving and getting Latitude and Longitude for a mp4 file in android 7.0

Tags: android, video, gps

Hi I have captured a video in android 7.0 and I got video file path. I need to store the Latitude and Longitude inside the video file i.e (Where the video was taken) like usually we do in images saving gps cordinates using Exif Interface. **But using Exif Interface for mp4 file didn't work**, instead I got an error:

**java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ExifInterface only supports saving attributes on JPEG formats.**

I thought of using the below code to save and fetch lat,long for video files also, but its not working.
*This is the code I am using to save and get gps co-ordinates for images :*

### Saving Latitude and Longitude for a image:

```
public void setImageLatitudeLongitude(File imagePath, double imageLat, double imageLong) {
        Log.e("Cordinates", "LAT : " + imageLat + "," + " LONG : " + imageLong);
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath.getPath());
            int num1Lat = (int) Math.floor(imageLat);
            int num2Lat = (int) Math.floor((imageLat - num1Lat) * 60);
            double num3Lat = (imageLat - ((double) num1Lat + ((double) num2Lat / 60))) * 3600000;

            int num1Lon = (int) Math.floor(imageLong);
            int num2Lon = (int) Math.floor((imageLong - num1Lon) * 60);
            double num3Lon = (imageLong - ((double) num1Lon + ((double) num2Lon / 60))) * 3600000;

            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, num1Lat + "/1," + num2Lat + "/1," + num3Lat + "/1000");
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, num1Lon + "/1," + num2Lon + "/1," + num3Lon + "/1000");

            Log.e("DMS LAT", num1Lat + "/1," + num2Lat + "/1," + num3Lat + "/1000");
            Log.e("DMS LONG", num1Lon + "/1," + num2Lon + "/1," + num3Lon + "/1000");
            if (imageLat > 0) {
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N");
            } else {
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "S");
            }

            if (imageLong > 0) {
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E");
            } else {
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "W");
            }

            exif.saveAttributes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

### Getting Latitude and Longitutde from an image:

```
public ArrayList getImageLatitudeLongitude(File imagePath) {
        double imageLat = 0.0, imageLong = 0.0;
        ArrayList<Double> arrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath.getPath());
            String latitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
            String longitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);

            if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                imageLat = convertToDegree(latitude);
                imageLong = convertToDegree(longitude);
                Log.e("Convert LAT", String.valueOf(convertToDegree(latitude)));
                Log.e("Convert LONG", String.valueOf(convertToDegree(longitude)));
            }
            arrayList.add(imageLat);
            arrayList.add(imageLong);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            arrayList.add(imageLat);
            arrayList.add(imageLong);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arrayList;
    }



private Float convertToDegree(String stringDMS) {
        Float result = null;
        String[] DMS = stringDMS.split(",", 3);

        String[] stringD = DMS[0].split("/", 2);
        Double D0 = new Double(stringD[0]);
        Double D1 = new Double(stringD[1]);
        Double FloatD = D0 / D1;

        String[] stringM = DMS[1].split("/", 2);
        Double M0 = new Double(stringM[0]);
        Double M1 = new Double(stringM[1]);
        Double FloatM = M0 / M1;

        String[] stringS = DMS[2].split("/", 2);
        Double S0 = new Double(stringS[0]);
        Double S1 = new Double(stringS[1]);
        Double FloatS = S0 / S1;

        result = new Float(FloatD + (FloatM / 60) + (FloatS / 3600));

        return result;
    }
```

And also how to get the latitude and longitude of the video file? Has anyone come across the same issue as I am facing, if so kindly suggest a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about reading the mp4 specification? Look where to store meta data.

Comment: @AlexWien Hi, so you are saying that I should go and look more deep into  mp4 file specifications ?

Answer (score 4):

ExifInterface only supports get attributes on image file.
You can use MediaMetadataRetriever class to get location data of video mp4 file. For example:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
    String location = mediaMetadataRetriever
            .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_LOCATION);
```

Comment: I tried this solution but its return always null in above android 10+ devices. It works perfectly below Android 11 devices. Is their any alternative solution available to get location data of any video file?